# how to upgrade to C# 5.0? access to modified closure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I feel a bit silly asking this. Please don't bash me too hard.

Lately I have been using .Net framework 4.5 and Visual C# 2012 with a pre-C# 5.0 compiler; and Visual Studio 2012.

I started working with Tasks, and got annoyed with "access to modified closure" notices from Resharper. I then read that if I upgrade to .Net framework 4.5.2 and upgrade to post-C# 5.0 that it has "fixes" to `for` and `foreach` such that I don't have to create a temporary variable within the curly brackets of the loop because of the shared context.

So I thought great, this will be an easy fix. And I did the following:

1) Checked that I am using Visual Studio 2012, and that it is compatible with both the new 4.5.2 framework and  C# 5.0 ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language))

2) I then downloaded and installed the developer's version of .Net 4.5.2 ([here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637))

3) I then targeted each of my projects in my solution to use .Net 4.5.2 instead of .Net 4.5. I rebuild, ran my unit tests, and had all green lights.

4) I then went to the Task code, and tried to remove the temporary variable. Lo' and Behold it still warns me about **access to modified closure**; for example:

```
    int numTasks = 1000;

    var tasks = new Task<int>[numTasks];

    for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
        tasks[i] = Task.Delay(1).ContinueWith(a => i); // <-- warning
```

The above code, because of the Shared Context, will generate faulty output. With .Net 4.5, and pre-C# 5.0, the way around this is to introduce a temp variable like this:

```
    int numTasks = 1000;

    var tasks = new Task<int>[numTasks];

    for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
    {
        int i1 = i;
        tasks[i] = Task.Delay(1).ContinueWith(a => i1); <-- no warning, works great
    }
```

Of course I do not like this because it is ugly and has to be commented for my coworkers to understand. I'd much rather use the new version of C# and the .Net framework.

I next thought, "how can I check if I have C# 5.0 installed and used by Visual Studio 2012?" And that is where I got stuck. My Visual Studio 2012 environment seems to still be using C# 4.5. I evidence this with the fact that the **access to modified closure** issue did not resolve after performing the upgrade steps that I listed above.

Can someone please help me understand how to get rid of the ****access to modified closure**** issue, hopefully by upgrading to C# 5.0 (if that is indeed my issue).

Thanks

Comment: I'm far from an expert on this, but I think that's a compiler/Visual Studio related change. You might not be something you can just drop in, you would have to use VS 2013

Comment: Hmm, you need new co-workers if correct code upsets them.  C# v5 only fixes it for foreach, not for for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is entirely correct.  You are closing over a variable that is later modified.  The example code that you provided behaves no differently in C# 4.0 and C# 5.0 (or C# 3.0 or C# 6.0).

In C# 5.0 *only `foreach` loops* were altered such that the loop variable is re-created on each iteration.  `for` loops were unchanged, and the semantics of closures is unchanged.

Comment: Eric Lippert has a great blog post about this named [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Comment: Of course...I should have read more closely. Thanks everyone for the quick answers.